# Array to merge same value as total count

Tags: php, arrays

**data array**

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [1] => 7
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [2] => 7
            )
    
        [2] => Array
            (
                [3] => 7
            )
    
        [3] => Array
            (
                [4] => 7
            )
    
        [4] => Array
            (
                [4] => 7
            )
    
        [5] => Array
            (
                [5] => 7
            )
    
        [6] => Array
            (
                [5] => 7
            )
    
        [7] => Array
            (
                [6] => 7
            )
    
        [8] => Array
            (
                [1] => 8
            )  

        [9] => Array
            (
                [2] => 8
            )  
    )
```

**Final result**

```
$fianl = array(
               '7' => 6,
               '8' => 2
              );
```

Question: I have one array will store the duplicate value data then need to be loop the array to find out the total count number by the value id, it's will not be count if the same value have count before. I stuck in this logic for quite some times :(. Does anyone can help me.

Comment: Hi there, you should really include one of your attempts, even if it's a failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$values = [
    [1 => 7], 
    [2 => 7],
    [3 => 7],
    [4 => 7],
    [4 => 7],
    [5 => 7],
    [5 => 7],
    [6 => 7],
    [1 => 8],
    [2 => 8],
];

foreach($values as $arr) {
    $items[reset($arr)][] = key($arr);
}
$items  = array_map('array_unique', $items);
$result = array_map('count', $items);
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  7 => 6,
  8 => 2,
)
```

You can loop through your original array, and build sub arrays with the values as keys and the keys as values.  Then filter out duplicates, and count.

You may want to dump the `$items` array before the `array_map`, to see the data structure, before filtering and counting.

Comment: @id'7238, yes that's an optimisation.  But it might be at the expense of readability.